# how to eliminate unnecessary characters from html using rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I tried to scrap html page however faced some errors. This page is written by Korean character so when i used `read_html` function, used `encoding = "EUC-KR"` as below :

```
url = 'http://www.38.co.kr/html/forum/com_list/index.htm?menu=nostock&keyword=&key1=&key2=&page=1' 
txt = read_html(url, encoding = 'EUC-KR')
```

Some pages are scrapped very well, but particular pages could not be scrapped because those pages could not be converted to "EUC-KR" due to specific character such as �

How can i do?

Comment: My connection times out when I try to check out the link you provided. Any other link that reliably works? And by the way, have you tried to read with UTF8 encoding?

Comment: yeah i tried "UTF-8" but did not translated to korean. only showed english. so  i want to use "EUC-KR". and another pages could apply for  euc-kr ,specific pages included the character did not apply for euc-kr, occurring the error